# Python outputting empty file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract some basic info on individuals in an input file from a master file however I am receiving an empty file every time.

I have two .txt files with no headers:

1. Input file with list of Individual numeric IDs eg. 1671198506
2. Master file with Individual IDs information eg. 1671198506,Call Rate,SNP Name,B,B

I want to extract the Individuals in the input file from the master file.
This is the code I have tried so far but I am getting an empty output file.

```
IDs=open("IDs.txt","r").readlines()
Master_File=open("Master_File.txt","r").readlines()
Output=open("Output.txt", "w")

ID_list={}

for i in IDs:
    ID_a=i.split()[0]
    if ID_a not in ID_list:
        ID_list[ID_a]=1       
        
for i in Master_File:
    splitline=i.split()
    ani=splitline[0]
    if ani in ID_list:
        Output.write(i)
Output.close()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you wany `splitline=i.split(',')`, the separator in `Master_File` is `,`. In any case you should debug the program and see if the values of the variables are what you are expecting them to be.

Comment: @Guy I deleted my comment but I thought you had misplaced your closing quote.

Comment: Without any indication of what the input file looks like, we can't really guess what's actually wrong here. Please [edit] to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You may want to split each line in master file with `,`. Also you'd better write each record to a new line. Like this:

```
IDs=open("IDs.txt","r").readlines()
Master_File=open("Master_File.txt","r").readlines()
Output=open("Output.txt", "w")

ID_list={}

for i in IDs:
    ID_a=i.split()[0]
    if ID_a not in ID_list:
        ID_list[ID_a]=1       
        
for i in Master_File:
    splitline=i.split(',')
    ani=splitline[0]
    if ani in ID_list:
        Output.write(i+'\n')
Output.close()
```

Or a more readable version:

```
ids=set(open("IDs.txt","r").readlines())

out_str = '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in open("Master_File.txt","r") if line.split(',')[0] in ids])

Output=open("Output.txt", "w")
Output.write(out_str)
Output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As already been mentioned in comments you need `splitline=i.split(',')`. But there other changes you should consider:

1. You should follow the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
2. You should use context managers, i.e. `with open(...) as file-name:` for opening files so that they are automatically closed even if an abnormal termination occurs. This also alleviates you from having to explicitly issue a `close` statement.
3. You should avoid having to read your input files into memory at once with `readlines` if there is no need for that. While that may be not a problem for small files, what if your input files are gigabytes in size?
4. Use the proper data structures where called for. You are using a dictionary for `ID_list` (poorly named) where a set is the appropriate type to use.
5. Choose your variable names so that they have meaning.

```py
id_set = set()
with open("IDs.txt", "r") as id_file:
    for line in id_file:
        id_a = line.split()[0] # or id_a = line.strip()
        id_set.add(id_a)

with open("Master_File.txt", "r") as master, open("Output.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in master:
        ani = line.split(',')[0]
        if ani in id_set:
            output.write(line)
```